# How do I expand a hard drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an Ubuntu VM which originally had a 126 GB HDD. In Hyper-V I have extended the partition to 500 GB. How do I reflect this change in the VM?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of expanding the disk size of a VM.

Once you expanded on hypervisor (doesn't matter what hypervisor is) the next step would be to login into your Vm and do the rest of the operation.

If the Vm is a server, so without GUI/desktop then a combination of fdisk and resize2fs is the best choice if you have normal (non-LVM) partitioning system.

Differently, if you have LVM setup then a combination of pvcreate+lvextend+resize2fs is the best way to do.

http://mwsite.net/2010/04/19/extend-a-lvm-volume-in-a-hyper-v-linux-vm/

If the VM you have is desktop then you can use simply gparted:

http://www.itworld.com/article/2833066/virtualization/how-to-extend-a-linux-virtual-machine-partition-in-hyper-v.html

Comment: Hi & thank you for replying. It is Ubuntu Server 14.4

Answer (score 0):

1. add a drive.
2. use [fdisk / parted](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html) to format the drive
3. IF you are using [LVM](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HOWTO-INDEX/howtos.html) (whatever) add the extend Or

   Mount /dev/newdrive /new drive
4. You need mirror copy the disk use LVM. / RAID
5. Try Greyhole after point 2.
6. Try point 4 after 2 . ( 2 is important )